# Login authentication with curl

Tags: php, angularjs, curl

I want to login using JIRA API with curl operation.

I having  problem in curl operation. I have main URL in JIRA_URL.'/demo/111'; values for $username and $password are passed in the function correctly but shows the status 'failure'. Is any issues in my curl code

```
function JIRA_authenticate($username, $password) {

     $url = JIRA_URL . '/demo/111';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // ssl ensure cert
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1); /// ssl ensure cert

    $issue_list = (curl_exec($curl));
    echo $issue_list;

    return $issue_list;
}
```

Comment: Are you running local machine?

Comment: yes running in local machine

Comment: use [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) library for this type of calls, its pretty easy

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what you are trying to achieve with this code.
Are you trying to get a ticket info, post an issue? You are just using the API...

Well here's a script that works with the JIRA API.

```
<?php
$username = 'test';
$password = 'test';
$url = "https://xxxxx.xxxxxxx.net/rest/api/2/project";

$ch = curl_init();

$headers = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$test = "This is the content of the custom field.";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$ch_error = curl_error($ch);

if ($ch_error) {
    echo "cURL Error: $ch_error";
} else {
    echo $result;
}

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

This code is fetching a project from JIRA.
If you want to create issues, you will have to change the REST URL to /rest/api/2/issue/ and use "POST" instead of "GET" method.